# KeyDownHandler-Event in DataGrid and ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, onkeydown

I have a example Method OnKeyDownHandler:

```
    private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
         {
            if (sender == listBox)
                listItemDelete();
            if (sender == dataGrid)
                dataGridItemDelete();
        }
    }
```

I have a `DataGrid` and a `ListBox`. Now i want to delete a Item when i press the `Delete-Key` and an item is selected.

Now we go through the following situations:

I have a `SelectedItem` in my `listBox` and the focus on it. When I press the `Deletey-Key` the `OnKeyDownHandler-Event` would be triggered.

I have a `SelectedItem` in my `dataGrid` and the focus on it. When i press the `Delete-Key`, the `OnkeyDownHandler-Event` wouldn't be triggered.

When I press any other Key like the `Paste-Key`, the OnKeyDownHandler-Event would be triggered.

The event is not called when I press the `Delete-Key` on my `dataGrid`. Why is that? I can not explain it.

---

Edit: XAML-Code

```
<DataGrid KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" />

<ListBox KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" />
```

Comment: What does your XAML look like where the event is hooked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyDown` event on your `DataGrid` is being handled by the active cell. The `DataGridView` control is handling the event, not your code-behind. You could try using the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown` for the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If your question is answered, please mark it as solved.

Comment: Yes I have to wait 2 minutes for marking and I was away from the keyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you OnKeyDownHandler is attached to the listbox and not to the datagrid. You need something like `dataGrid.OnKeyDown += OnKeyDownHandler;` in you Window_Loaded or Page_Loaded or in XAML

```
<DataGrid ... OnKeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" ... ></DataGrid>
```

Comment: I have edit my Question with the XAML-Code. Why does it work so with other Keys(like the Paste-Key)?